# Modifying jQuery jsonp callback function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

I think I'm going to be stuck writing a messy dispatch function, but thought I'd check the S.O. community first to see if someone has come up with an easier solution.

Bless the World Bank for having an open API, but they have some implementation problems. First problem is their server doesn't implement CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, so that means JSONP instead of JSON. That wouldn't be a problem, except that they *don't* preserve the case of the callback function! To cite a specific example, I make the following request in my code:

```
var deferredRegionsRequest = $.getJSON(
    "http://api.worldbank.org/regions/?prefix=?",
    {format: "jsonp"}
);
```

(Yes, they use the parameter `prefix` instead of the traditional `callback`.)

jQuery dutifully creates a random callback function and issues the AJAX request as:

```
http://api.worldbank.org/regions/?prefix=jQuery18308848262811079621_1393981029347&format=jsonp&_=1393981029990
```

Note that the callback function has an uppercase `Q`.

The response that the World Bank returns, however, has renamed that callback to all lowercase!

```
jquery18308848262811079621_1393981029347([
    { "page": "1", "pages": "1", "per_page": "50", "total": "32" },
    [ {
        "id": "",
        "code": "AFR",
        "name": "Africa"
      }, {
...
```

Obviously that's not going to work. If I were just making a single request, it wouldn't be too painful to provide my own callback function and use the `jsonpCallback` parameter of `$.ajax()`. Unfortunately, I need to traverse and loop through their REST API, so I'll be making dozens of (parallel) API calls. I've checked a custom callback, and `this` is set to the global `window` object, so there doesn't seem to be any obvious way for a single callback function to manage multiple responses. It seems like I might be stuck with a messy, custom dispatcher implementation, which I'd really like to avoid.

The only alternative I've come up with so far is to define a `beforeSend` callback that takes the fully populated URL, parses it to find the callback function (`jQuery...`), creates a new callback function dynamically that's an all lowercase version of the original (`jquery...`), and does nothing by call the original. The hack quotient is so high my head spins, but I've verified that this does work:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    var prefix = settings.url.match(/prefix=(.*?)&/);
    if (prefix.length > 1) {
      var callback = prefix[1];
      if (callback !== callback.toLowerCase()) {
        window[callback.toLowerCase()] = 
          new Function("response", callback + "(response)");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I sure hope I'm missing something really simple and someone very kind will point it out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last alternative that you call a hack sounds like a mighty simple way to leverage all that jQuery does for you and just work around the one case issue by making your own function that's lowercase and just calling the mixed case one from it. Other than getting the World Bank to fix their server, this seems like the least hackish way of doing things to me. I can't see any better work-around.

If the jQuery callback function already exists at `beforeSend` time, then all you need to do is to create a global variable with the lowercase name and put a reference to the mixed cased function in it. You don't even have to create a function body.

So, if you see `jQuery18308848262811079621_1393981029347` in the URL in `beforeSend`, then you just do:

```
window.jquery18308848262811079621_1393981029347 = jQuery18308848262811079621_1393981029347;
```

I guess it might take `eval()` to make that work since you have the function's name as a string.  Or perhaps one of the geniuses here can figure out how to create that line of code without `eval()`.

---

Another option might be to make a single character patch to the jQuery library you use so it outputs only a lowercase string.

I think the "jQuery" string part comes from this:

```
jQuery.extend({
// Unique for each copy of jQuery on the page
expando: "jQuery" + ( core_version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
```

though it would take some debugging to confirm.

---

Or, it looks like maybe there's a callback function that creates the jsonpCallback name that could be either modified or replaced:

```
// Default jsonp settings
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    jsonpCallback: function() {
        var callback = oldCallbacks.pop() || ( jQuery.expando + "_" + ( ajax_nonce++ ) );
        this[ callback ] = true;
        return callback;
    }
});
```

---

I found that this would work in my demo JSONP app http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UM9NL/:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      var origCallback = settings.jsonpCallback;
      settings.url = settings.url.replace(/=jQuery/, "=jquery");
      window[origCallback.toLowerCase()] = function() {
          window[origCallback].apply(this, arguments);
      }
  }
});
```

And, this also works http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GXte2/:

```
// Default jsonp settings
(function() {
    var myajax_nonce = jQuery.now();
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: function() {
            var callback = ( jQuery.expando.toLowerCase() + "_" + ( myajax_nonce++ ) );
            this[ callback ] = true;
            return callback;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement; it makes me feel a little better. One thing to note, though, is that jQuery doesn't actually define the jsonp callback (`jQuery...`) until some point **after** it calls `beforeSend`. So just creating the global variable won't work. But creating a dynamic function won't be too too hard if that's what I'm left with.

Comment: @StephenThomas - ahh, ok.  Slightly more work to create the lowercase callback then, but it sounds like you know how to do that.

Comment: BTW, gonna up-vote this answer if, for no other reason, as thanks for reading my lengthy question.

Comment: @StephenThomas - I added another option to my answer.  You could make a single character patch to the jQuery library you include to change the "Q" to a lowercase.

Comment: Based on @jfriend00's comments I decided to take a shot at the hack. It does work, and I've updated the question with tested code. I'm still nervous about using something the jQuery docs [recommend against](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), but it seems the cleanest option. I'll let this sit for a day or so to see if anyone comes up with anything cleaner, but otherwise I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: @StephenThomas - I added two working versions of a fix.  Once is similar to yours (via ajaxSetup) though it uses a closure rather than a Function object.  The other one works by replacing the jsonpCallback function which creates the callback function name.